# Okay to amend migrations after migrate:reset?

Tags: laravel, laravel-migrations

I have a site in development so database structure is still in flux. If I run `migrate:reset`, this rollbacks all migrations. Am I, therefore, okay to amend the migrations - i.e. amend Schema closures and remove migration files etc - as opposed to adding more migrations to amend the DB structure? For example, client asked for certain functionality requiring a table, decides later he doesn't want it so I have a table in my migrations I will never use. Ideally I don't want this to appear in my migrations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need a table anymore in your project of course you can delete it's migration file.

When you run `php artisan migrate:reset` Laravel rolls back all migrations. But if you delete your migration file without rolling it back, Laravel will try to find that migration file to roll it back and when it can't find that file; it will throw an exception.

In such cases you can use `php artisan migrate:fresh`
With `migrate:fresh` Laravel doesn't try to find and roll back migrations, it just drops all tables and starts a fresh `migrations` table and migrates every file from start.

So; if you have changes on your migration files, anything, and if you are on development enviroment and nothing will affected: you can do whatever you want with your migration files and run `php artisan migrate:fresh` to drop every table and migrate them again.

Please check here: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#rolling-back-migrations